# How to resolve Appstore connnect Intents Extension Issue on build validate?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

After success build archive facing issue on build validation

> Intents Extension Issue. Your app includes an intents UI extension,
> but no other intents extensions. If apps contain intents UI
> extensions, they must contain other intents extensions as well.

[image]

Help me to resolve. Thanks in advance!